# How to keep Image data in file system with Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, blob, bytea, file-system, postgresql-15

I am wondering is there any way to store image type data (binary data) in postgresql not directly into the columns but resides in the file system but not gonna store the path link as text in database but store as binary type data using any kind of 3rd party open source technology or anything else.

I am using postgresql version 15.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. There is the option of using `file_fdw` to access a CSV file as a database table, but that is probably not what you are looking for.